# Do PI-SceI and PI-PspI from NEB work in each other's buffers?

Tags: cloning, restriction-enzymes

I'm considering a plasmid design strategy that would allow me to use restriction enzymes to exchange plasmid inserts among different backbones. In this case, the plasmids would first be made through MoClo assembly of pL1 inserts into different pL2 backbones. Then, ideally I could exchange the whole complete insert to another backbone at a later date without repeating the GG reaction.

To do this, I was thinking to use homing endonucleases, which have large footprints and are thus unlikely to show up in a given sequence. I already have I-SceI in the plasmids to use for linearization, so can't use that one. That would have been convenient because I-CeuI from NEB and I-SceI both are 100% active in CutSmart.

The other HE options from NEB are PI-SceI and PI-PspI. Neither work in any of the standard buffers, but use similar buffers as each other:

**1X NEBuffer™ PI-SceI**

- 10 mM MgCl2
- 1 mM DTT
- 10 mM Tris-HCl
- 100 mM KCl
- (pH 8.6 @ 25°C)

**1X NEBuffer™ PI-PspI**

- 10 mM Tris-HCl
- 10 mM MgCl2
- 1 mM DTT
- 150 mM KCl
- (pH 9.2 @ 25°C)

I'm wondering if anyone has tried using them at the same time in one or the other's buffer?

Alternatively, are there any other good HEs out there I should look into?

Finally, is this even worth it? Or should I just re-run the MoClo reactions into new backbones? Would that be more efficient and reduce hands-on effort?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Have you looked into gateway cloning?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. If you look carefully at the NEB site you will find that these enzymes require very different temperatures for activity (37°C vs. 65°C) ...

Comment: Oof you're right! PI-PspI only has 10% activity at 37°C. Bad idea....

Yeah Gateway is possible, though I try to avoid it if possible. Would be weird too because transferring in would cause PB to switch to RL or vice-versa. So I'd need BP and RL versions of each backbone depending on which way I wanted to switch. I think the simpler solution is to just replicate the Golden Gate into different backbones as needed. That's very efficient and not that time-consuming (esp with all calculations essentially pre-done).

Comment: If you have questions, you can always call NEB's tech support. You'll get to talk to a real person who actually understands the products and the science. (I used to work for a company that was spun out of NEB and has the same tech support model.)